# What do I do when trying to find a limit that first appears indeterminate but is actually defined (but not continuous)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry

Working on a beginner calculus problem and am perplexed.  I'm asked to find...

$$\lim_{x \to \pi/4} f(x) \frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt2 \cos x-1}$$

I found that the function was indeterminate at $x=\pi/4$ because inputting the value $\pi/4$ gave a result of $0/0$.  Visually, when graphed the function appears to have a limit of $2$ at this point.  So I was thinking that the limit would be 2, but I would have to set the condition that $x\neq\pi/4$.

But then my graphing calculator reported that at $x=\pi/4$ the function **is** in fact defined.  To verify this I used the trig identity $\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$ to find that...

$$ f(x)=\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt2 \cos x-1}$$

given that $\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$,

$$ f(x)=\frac{2\cos^2x-1}{\sqrt2 \cos x-1}$$

and then

$$ f(x)=\frac{(\sqrt2 \cos x-1)(\sqrt2 \cos x+1)}{\sqrt2 \cos x-1}$$
and finally

$$ f(x)=\sqrt2 \cos x+1=0$$

This matches what the calculator showed me, that the limit is $2$ but the value at $x=\pi/4$ is zero.  Here is the thing I can't wrap my head around.  How do I deal with the fact that the original function is indeterminate at this point?  Do I need to take this into account in my answer?  Or is it acceptable to simply state that the limit is 2 because I have shown that the function is defined.  Does it matter that it is not continuous?  Is the following answer sufficient?

$\lim_{x \to \pi/4} f(x)$ $\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt2 \cos x-1} = 2$

EDIT : I encounted the problem in the Limits section of Khan Academy's Differential Calculus.  It simply lists the answer as 2.

Comment: You might want to add the link to the problem from Khan Academy.

Comment: Found it. But do note that the explanation is provided there regardless if you got it correctly or not.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is wrong. Remember that you canceled out $\sqrt{2} \cos x - 1$ from the numerator and the denominator. This means that $$\frac{(\sqrt{2} \cos x - 1)(\sqrt2 \cos x+1)}{\sqrt2 \cos x-1} = \sqrt{2} \cos x + 1$$ if $\sqrt{2} \cos x - 1 \neq 0$. Otherwise, they are not the same. Even though $\sqrt{2} \cos x + 1$ exists at $x = \pi/4$, they are different.

Using the direct substitution principle, $\cos \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ so the limit is really $2$.

---

It is likely that you put $\sqrt{2} \cos x - 1$ instead of $\sqrt{2} \cos x + 1$. You may want to recheck that.